# Aws Lambda function triggers on a delay time for 2 out of 3 cron jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, cron, aws-event-bridge

I have a Lambda function that has 3 event triggers here are the Cron job for each:

> Cron 1: cron(50/1 22 * * ? *)
>
> Cron 2: cron(50/1 12 * * ? *)
>
> Cron 3: cron(*/15 * * * ? *)

Now Cron 2 Timestamp logs reads as follows, which is ok. Notice that it starts 2-3 seconds into the intended trigger:

```
10
2021-07-10T05:59:03.867-07:00
11
2021-07-10T05:59:03.867-07:00
12
2021-07-10T05:59:02.314-07:00
START
13
2021-07-10T05:58:02.988-07:00
END 
14
2021-07-10T05:58:02.988-07:00
15
2021-07-10T05:58:02.547-07:00
START
```

BUT Cron 1 & 3 starts over 30+ seconds into the intended trigger. I compared everything possible and there are no settings that are different (to my knowledge). Any idea why 2 of the 3 events have a delay but one doesn't? I understand a small 1-5 second delay by reading here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html but somethings seems to be off.

```
2021-07-10T06:30:37.253-07:00
2
2021-07-10T06:30:37.253-07:00
3
2021-07-10T06:30:33.929-07:00
4
2021-07-10T06:15:36.931-07:00
5
2021-07-10T06:15:36.931-07:00
6
2021-07-10T06:15:33.881-07:00
7
2021-07-10T06:00:34.037-07:00
8
2021-07-10T06:00:34.037-07:00
9
2021-07-10T06:00:33.596-07:00
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why that happens?

Answer (score 3):

The [precision](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html) of Event Bridge is one minute:

> All scheduled events use UTC+0 time zone, and the minimum precision for a schedule is one minute. Your scheduled rule **runs within that minute**, but not on the precise 0th second.

So your delays are **perfectly fine** and within the 1 minute interval.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and yes I did read that section of the documentation. I just find it strange that one trigger calls within 2-3 seconds but the others doesn't. I would be ok if all 3 were the same but what makes one bridge different than the other?

Comment: @mojo_123431 Its not strange. Resolution is 1 minute, thus you should not think about any seconds. There are no seconds in Event Bridge.